# Yibum & Chalitzah: Questionable hekesh with wife's sister

Tags: marriage, lomdus, yibbum-chalitza-levirate, masechet-yevamot

In [*Yevamoth* 3b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=14&daf=3b&format=pdf), we learn that the reason for exempting fourteen women (of the fifteen enumerated in *mishna* 1:1) and their co-wives from *yibum* (levirate marriage) and *chalitzah* (the decision not to do levirate marriage) is due to a *hekesh* (textual comparison) with the case of a man's wife's sister.

> מה אחות אשה מיוחדת שהיא ערוה וחייבין על זדונה כרת ועל שגגתה חטאת ואסורה ליבם, אף כל שהיא ערוה וחייבין על זדונה כרת ועל שגגתה חטאת אסורה ליבם
>
> As a wife's sister is singled out in that she is a forbidden relative, the penalty for presumptuous intercourse with her is *kareth* (spiritual excision) and for unwitting intercourse a sin-offering, and she is forbidden to the levir, so also any woman who is a forbidden relative, and the penalty for presumptuous intercourse with whom is *kareth* and for unwitting intercourse a sin-offering, is forbidden to the levir. [translation from [here](http://halakhah.com/yebamoth/yebamoth_3.html)]

The same *hekesh* is then used to exclude the co-wives of the fourteen women from *yibum* and *chalitzah*.

The *gemara* then comments that this *hekesh* shows that a different group of six women do not exempt their co-wives from *yibum* and *chalitzah*, by finding an attribute of the case of a man's wife's sister that is not shared by the cases of the six women, namely, that in the case of a man's wife's sister, the sister may marry another one of the *yavam*'s (levir's) brothers, whereas the six women may never marry any of the brothers of the *yavam*.

**My question: why do we not argue that the first *hekesh* is invalid, by saying that in the case of a man's wife's sister, the sister is permitted after the death of the wife, whereas in the other fourteen cases, the women never become permitted to the *yavam*?**

It's clear that we're willing to use such an argument by dint of having done so to include co-wives of the six women in *yibum* and *chalitzah*.  Why do we not do so here?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/48097/440

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice question.

Tosfos there deal with a similar question that I believe would answer yours, too:

> מה אחות אשה מיוחדת כו'. וא''ת מה לאחות אשה שכן בידו לרבות כדפריך בפ'
>   הבא על יבמתו (לקמן דף נד. ושם) וי''ל דאהיקש דר' יונה דסוף שמעתין (דף
>   ח.) סמיך

According to Tosfos, this Gemara is working in tandem with the hekesh of R' Yona which specifically signals to us to link all of the arayos regarding their halachos.

As to what the Gemara's point by the "6 arayos" is then, I think the Gemara is not merely pointing out a mere difference (pircha), but instead is explaining that the whole concept of exempting from the mitzva of yibum can only be discussed if there is a conceivable case of yibum, which by the 6, there isn't.

Comment: The _hekesh_ of R' Yona says that we could compare all the _arayot_ to a brother's wife to permit _yibum_, and so along comes עליה to forbid.  But that still relies on the viability of a _hekesh_ with a wife's sister to include in that argumentation _arayot_ besides a wife's sister, no?

Comment: @magicker72 It seems from Tosfos that R' Yona's hekesh says to connect all of the arayos in spite of possible differences between them. We have a rule: אין משיבין על ההיקש, We don't point out differences between 2 subjects when the Torah clearly signals to compare them. I think that's what Tosfos means.

Comment: I've edited your answer to put the Tosfos in blockquotes, which I think looks nicer. As an aside, you might want to check out other [tag:lomdus] questions; you'll probably find some interesting things there :)